# Casting object to Dictionary<Guid,AbstractBaseClass> without first casting to Dictionary<Guid,DerivedClass>

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting

If I have an abstract base class called MyBaseClass, and a class deriving from MyBaseClass called MyDerivedClass, is there a way to cast an object that I know is a Dictionary<Guid,MyDerivedClass> to a Dictionary<Guid,MyBaseClass> instead?

I get an invalid cast error when I do:

```
var dict = (Dictionary<Guid,MyBaseClass>)obj; // Where obj is "object" type but I know is a Dictionary<Guid,MyDerivedClass>. 
// This throws an invalid cast error.
```

The thing that has me confused is that casting an obj that I know is a List<MyDerivedClass> to a List<MyBaseClass> actually works. This works:

```
var list = (List<MyBaseClass>)obj; // Where obj is "object" type but I know is a List<MyDerivedClass>
// This works
```

Is there any way to cast an object that is Dictionary<Guid,MyDerivedClass> to Dictionary<Guid,MyBaseClass> without first casting to Dictionary<Guid,MyDerivedClass>? I'd like to avoid have to try casting each derived class if possible.

Comment: What you say about being able to cast a list is not true. Either your `obj` is already a `List<MyBaseClass>` or that line will throw an exception. Note that such a list can still contain only `MyDerivedClass`es, but that's not the same as _being_ a `List<MyDerivedClass>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET uses reified generics, so (unlike covariant/contravariant interfaces and arrays) you cannot cast generic classes to have a different signature from what the object actually *is*. Your example with a List actually doesn't behave the way you say it does:

```
object obj = new List<MyDerivedClass>();
var list = (List<MyBaseClass>)obj; // invalid cast exception
```

You can create a *new* dictionary, though.

```
var dict = ((Dictionary<Guid, MyDerivedClass>)obj)
    .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => (MyBaseClass)d.Value);
```

This will create a copy, and is more expensive than a cast, but for most use cases it won't significantly impact your application's performance.

You could technically create your own class that *wraps* a differently-typed dictionary and implements an interface like `IDictionary<,>`, so you could avoid the up-front cost of creating the dictionary but incur slightly more cost as you use the dictionary.

But, in summary, there is no way to simply *cast* a generic class to a type that it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but in my list case, it actually does seem to be properly casting my obj which is List<MyDerivedClass> to IEnumberable<MyBaseClass> (not List<MyBaseClass> like I had said in my question). I know the obj is a List<MyDerivedClass> because it is coming from a PropertyInfo.GetValue() call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have multiple derived classes and I was hoping I could do a catch-all cast that would just cast it to the base class. In that case I will just resort to trying to cast it to each of the derived class dictionaries.

Comment: `IEnumerable<>` is an interface, and [its generic parameter is _covariant_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-6.0#type-parameters). That works because an `IEnumerable<MyDerivedClass>` only allows you to get `MyDerivedClass` instances _out_ of the methods (as return values), and any `MyDerivedClass` is known to be a `MyBaseClass`. But a `List<MyDerivedClass>` or `IList<MyDerivedClass>` allows you to pass a `MyDerivedClass` into the `Add` method, and not all `MyBaseClass` instances are `MyDerivesClass`es.

Comment: There is an `IReadOnlyDictionary<>` interface, which you might think could be covariant on the item type, but due to the way the CLI thinks of `out` parameters as the same as `ref` parameters, methods like `TryGetValue` prevent the generic parameter from being covariant. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2175

Comment: The more you know! Thanks for the clarification